# Why is my Chrome Developer Tool for mobile ugly

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

after update of my Chrome, developer tools started to look ugly. It's really annoying and it's not UX friendly. Is there any way how to turn it back?

[image: this is new ugly interface]

this old one that i want
[image: old nice interface]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to revert to the old user interface. The current interface is what will be continued to get refined going forward.

If you have specific suggestions to improve this interface then you can file issues on the [Chromium Issue Tracker](https://crbug.com). Please try to keep a *single suggestion*  to an issue, this way each idea can have its own discussion and work assigned. Issues with multiple suggestions of feedback are difficult to have a good conversation around.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the right side docking location?

You can click on the 3 vertical dots in the top corner next the X to close it and it will show you the options to change the docking location.

Alternatively, on Mac, you can use the shortcut key <kbd>**CMD**</kbd>+<kbd>**SHIFT**</kbd>+<kbd>**D**</kbd> on Windows <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd>+<kbd>**SHIFT**</kbd>+<kbd>**D**</kbd> to toggle the docking locations quickly.